# Emacs 23 built-in python.el indentation broken using tabs with width 4

Tags: python, emacs, tabs, indentation

I've been using the version of `python.el` [found here](http://www.loveshack.ukfsn.org/emacs/python.el) for a couple of years in Emacs 23  without incident. I decided to try the stock `python.el`, and ran into a strange issue:

When using tabs for indentation and a tab width of 4, the stock `python.el` will indent two tab characters for every level instead of 1.  With a tab width of 5, the indentation will be 1 tab plus 3 spaces.  So, when `indent-tabs-mode` is `t`, `indent-for-tab-command` seems to always force a tab size of 8, regardless of what `tab-width` is set to.

Is there some other tab-related variable I can set to override this behavior?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, just a note: be sure the hard tab stop is always 8 spaces.  Smaller indentations should always be made using spaces, never by changing the hard tab width, or you'll cause yourself and others serious migraines later on.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow.  At work, Python code uses tabs for indentation (I hate this, but accept it).  I want Emacs to render tabs as 4 spaces wide.  Are you saying this is bad?

Comment: Have you considered using python-mode?  It's maintained by some of Python's core developers: https://launchpad.net/python-mode

Comment: I'm sure I have, at some point.  I've tried out a variety of non-built-in Python modes…  I figured I'd see if I could make do with the built-in one, for now.  Thanks for the pointer, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've figured this out after digging through the source code for the stock Emacs 23 `python.el` and [the newest `python.el` on the block](https://github.com/fgallina/python.el).

Given these settings in a `python-mode` buffer, indentation with tabs and a tab-width of 4 works as expected in stock `python.el`:

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode t
      tab-width 4
      python-indent 4)
```

For the new `python.el`, you need to change `python-indent` to `python-indent-offset`.  I'm using both settings for both modes without issue.

If someone has a better solution to this problem, please add it and I'll gladly accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

stuck using tabs? check

trying out emacs 23 with python.el? check

I've run into the same wall as you recently... what I've learned is that I truly hate tabs and that I find python's whitespace significance incredibly annoying.

Are you setting tab-width in your init or with customize?

**I had to make sure to change tab-width in the "Editing Basics" section via customize to get "4 space" tabs to stick** (something to do with global/local scope).  But the fun doesn't end there... python.el seems to only want to indent to the first tab-stop (column 4 now) and no further no matter what I set indent-tab-mode or tab-always-indent to.  I finally gave up and went back to using python-mode.el, which has it's own set of idiosyncrasies, but at least python code is indenting "correctly".

Comment: I'm setting my tab-width directly in my `.emacs`, not using `customize`.  It turns out there's an extra `python-indent` variable that (appears) to make stock `python.el` do what I want.